# How to increase the size of gridviewitem on mouse over in uwp?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Normally on mouseover we get a grey border highlighting the gridviewitem on mouse over. But instead of that I would slightly want to increase the size of the gridviewitem like a little pop and on when the mouse leaves bring it back to the normal size. Please note the increase in size/pop up should not disturb the rest of the gridviewitems.

My code currently is very basic:

```
<GridView x:Name="contentGV" Margin="18,10,18,18"  
                          Width="Auto">
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Margin="5,5,25,5" MaxWidth="145" Height="220">
                    <Grid Background="{Binding LogoBG}" CornerRadius="25" Height="120" Width="120">
                        <Border Height="120" Width="120" CornerRadius="25">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding LogoUrl}" />
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Title" 
                                   MaxLines="2" Width="120"
                                   Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136764/how-to-expand-a-listview-item-on-selectionchanged-event-in-windows-10/36140944#36140944. I hope you are looking for that? and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167365/how-to-create-drop-down-menu-foreach-row-in-gridview-onclick-uwp-windows-10-app

Comment: It seems when you change size of the item rest of the items size gets effected. In your case better use ListView

Comment: Is there no way we can achieve this in gridview

Comment: And as we can see even in listview the other items are moving away. I dont want it to affect other gridviewitems the pop up should be overlayed on the other gridviewitems in that case.

Comment: I guess You can override ItemsPanel of gridview

Comment: But I still don't get it since the gridviewitem size is already fixed in the beginning if I try increasing the size, the elements inside get increased but at the same time they are cropped. There should be a simpler solution I hope.

Comment: Did you try editing visual states for mouse hover? If not edit item container style in blend, increase height property of grid in mouse over visual state( or similar states)

Comment: I would think you could add an animation in the PointerOverState of the [style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx) to give a negative margin to a background element of an item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my mind, there is no perfect solution for this, because if we make a big change on the size of the GridViewItem, it will affect others GridViewItem.

One workaround for this is that we can change the size of the Grid inside the DataTemplate, in this way it will look like we have implemented a popup on the GridViewItem.

But please note that since the GridViewItem has a gray border and it has the fixed size, so if we have changed a lot of the Grid, then the content of the Grid may be truncated. And it will work fine if we make a little change on the size of the Grid based on your gray border.

In order to change the size the Grid, one way is that we can change the height and width of the Grid. In this way it will not change the others controls’ size that it are inside the Grid, for example the font size of the text.

The other way is that we can perform a [CompositeTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br228105) on the Grid and change the [CompositeTransform.ScaleX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.compositetransform.scalex) and [CompositeTransform.ScaleY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.compositetransform.scaley.aspx) to stretch or shrink the Grid. In this way the others controls that are inside the Grid will also be stretched or shrinked.

We can implement the above requirement by using the VisualState or .cs code.

I have created an example to implement it in code behind by performing a [CompositeTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br228105) on the Grid, in my example for handling the move over operation, I have used the [PointerEntered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerentered) event. And I use the [PointerExited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerexited.aspx) event to handle the move leave operation and set the [CompositeTransform.ScaleX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.compositetransform.scalex.aspx) and [CompositeTransform.ScaleY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.compositetransform.scaley.aspx) value as 1 to let the GridViewItem return to the normal size inside the[PointerExited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerexited.aspx) event.

The XAML Code:

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited"> 
                   ……

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

The .CS code:

```
private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid testGrid = sender as Grid;
        testGrid.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { ScaleX = 1.2, ScaleY = 1.2 };

    }

    private void Grid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid testGrid = sender as Grid;
        testGrid.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { ScaleX = 1, ScaleY = 1 };
    }
```

The result:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! And one more thing is there anyway I could make the transition smoother? And also the grid is transforming but as you can see it is only increasing in size in the right and bottom direction is there any other way to increase it in all the the directions so its much more smoother?